# Distribution of the product of $n$ i.i.d log-normal random variables

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent log-normal random variables such that $$log(X_i)\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)\ \ \forall i=1,\ldots,n$$

Then what can be said about the distribution of the random variable $Y$?

Where $Y$ is defined as
 $$Y=X_1\times\cdots\times X_n$$

Comment: You should be able to prove yourself that it is lognormal

Comment: If not, just [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lognormal+product) for answers.

Comment: I already have an answer. As per my calculations, $logY\sim N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$. However, the book I am using says the mean is $\mu$ instead of $n\mu$. Which is correct?